# Error in getting gson while using Get Method in Retrofit

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I don't understand all thing I have set in String. but still got this problem. when I test my web API got no issue on this thing.. but when I implement got this problem..

here my error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path
```

here is my code to call get Section

```
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long itemID) {
                if (position >= 0 && position < goodModelArrayList.size()) {
                    String section= goodModelArrayList.get(position).getSection();
                    //getSelectedCategoryData(section);
                    restService.getService().getSection(section, new Callback<VW_AC_Line_>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(VW_AC_Line_ student, Response response) {
                            Toast.makeText(Viewattendance.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(Viewattendance.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Viewattendance.this, "Selected Category Does not Exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
```

here my data class to call

```
public class VW_AC_Line_ {

    public int ID;
    public String Section;

    public int getID(){
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int id){
        this.ID = id;
    }
    public String getSection() {
        return Section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.Section = section;
    }
}
```

here is my  calling method web api

```
    @GET("/api/VW_AC_LINE_/deparment/{section}")
    public void getSection(@Path("section") String section, Callback<VW_AC_Line_> callback);
```

here is web api calling

```
[{"ID":2665,"Section":"IT"}].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are getting below response(array of objects) but expecting object.

array of objects: [{VW_AC_Line_:{
"a":2,"b":3}}]

Expected: {VW_AC_Line_:{
"a":2,"b":3}}

Comment: [{"ID":2665,"Section":"IT"}].. this what i get from my web api

Answer (score 0):

```
restService.getService().getSection(section, new Callback<ArrayList<VW_AC_Line_>>() {
    @Override
    public void success(ArrayList<VW_AC_Line_> student, Response response) {
        Toast.makeText(Viewattendance.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        Toast.makeText(Viewattendance.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

});
```

Call it as array list, since the web API recall in array